# Is there a way to define providers, declarations, imports for multiple tests

Tags: jasmine, angular6, karma-jasmine

I'm starting writing unit tests for our projects, for some reason we don't have any unit tests before. I'm currently trying to make the default test to pass, and I have to define some imports, declarations, and providers. We have 44 components/services now, and for 3 of the unit tests I work on, they use same imports, declarations, and providers.

I'm just wondering if there is a way to define imports, declarations, and providers for all of the tests.

```
it('should create', () => {
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you provide some more examples of what you currently have (in code) and what you have tried?

Comment: Did my answer help you or do you need anything else explained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create testing module with set of common dependencies like this:

```
@NgModule({
  // ...whatever you need
  providers: [
    { provide: Dependency, useClass: DependencyMock },
  ]
})
export class CommonTestingModule {
}
```

and then in tests

```
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
      CommonTestingModule,
      ...
    ],
  ...
  })
  ...
});
```

You can create more modules for parts of applications that can be used in a few places its similar to modules provided by angular like `HttpClientTestingModule`

Comment: Hi, Thank you, this is very helpful and I have some follow up question. First is I added all of the declarations, imports, and providers in common test module, even those only used few times, would this affect anything? Like would this slow the tests which don't need those configs?. Second is when I try to add HttpHandler in providers, it tells me that  Type 'typeof HttpHandler' is not assignable to type 'Provider'. I searched it and found someone said it is included in HttpClientModule, then I tried that and it didn't work. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: It may have some impact on build time like you put `TestBed.configureTestingModule` in `beforeEach` that means it needs to run configuration before each test. That's why I would suggest to keep in `CommonTestingModule` bare minimum that is needed everywhere and anything that is used only in specific situations should have separate module.

Comment: Second, I think `HttpHandler ` is an abstract class that is not used straight in dependency injection so you probably want to provide one of its derived classes like `HttpBackend` which seems to be overridden by `HttpClientTestingModule` https://angular.io/api/common/http/testing/HttpClientTestingModule